# Absolute maximum and minimum value of continuous function on interval $I = [a, b]$

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ be a continuous funtion on interval $I=[a,b]$. Then $f$ has the absolute maximum value and $f$ attains it at least once in $I$. Also, $f$ has the absolute minimum value and attains it at least once in $I$.

This is a theorem.

A constant function is also continuous, but I can't find any absolute maximum or minimum value in it. Can someone help me with this condition?

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x)=c$ for all $x\in [a,b]$ then $f(x) \leq c$ for all $x\in [a,b]$ and $f(x) \geq c$ for all $x\in [a,b]$, so in fact, any $x\in [a,b]$  is an absolute maximum and absolute minimum.

Comment: You mean to say if f(x)=24 in an interval [2,4] then 24 will be called both its absolut maximum and minimum value

Comment: Remember that if $f$ is defined in $[a,b]$ then $f(x_0)$ is maximum if $f(x_0) \geq f(x)$ for all $x\in [a,b]$ and the same goes with the minimum. If $f(x)=24$ for all $x \in [2,4]$ then $f(2)=24 \geq f(x)$ for all $x\in [2,4]$ in fact, the equality holds, but the inequality is still true.

Comment: Are you sure that f(x0) can also be equal to f(x) for in my book it is just mentioned that f(x0) is greater or less than f(x) for all x in the interval